# Within the United States (Pittsburgh), when merging onto a lane, which turn signal do you use?

Tags: usa, legal, driving, pennsylvania

While driving in Pennsylvania, specifically in Schenley Park in Pittsburgh, I was merging from a side-street to a main road, as seen in the picture below. I had stopped at the stop-sign, checked for traffic, then proceeded on, whereupon a police officer started flashing his lights at me. He asked where I was coming from, and whether I'd had my turn signal on, stating that he hadn't seen one. I answered him honestly that I was coming from karaoke in Oakland, and that I had had it on, the left turn signal specifically. He did some checks on his laptop and then sent me on my way. In retrospect, since it was a little after 2 AM, he was probably randomly pulling people over, knowing that the odds were that he could find someone who was driving inebriated after leaving the closing bar, the turn signal being a flimsy excuse for probable cause. That said, it made me wonder, which turn signal should be on in this sort of situation?

[image: Merging onto Panther Hollow Rd]

One option is to have the left turn signal on, since you are merging left into traffic. On the other hand, I'd come to a complete stop, and a left turn signal might confuse people into thinking that I planned on a left turn (not feasible here, but possible in some other merging situations) and one does sort of have to turn right from the side street to get onto the main street. Reading through the PA traffic manual didn't help. Poking through the Kentucky and Ohio ones (they were convenient) didn't bring up any helpful laws for how to properly signal a merge. Is there a standard rule in Pittsburgh, in Allegheny County, in Pennsylvania, or in the United States in general, that I can rely on?

Comment: The answers below seem fine, but there are exceptions.  In Boston, for example, you either use both signals or none.  And certainly no brake lights, there, when merging onto a highway or especially a rotary: Just floor it.

Comment: The relevant section is [Title 75, Chapter 33, Subchapter C, § 3334](http://www.legis.state.pa.us/cfdocs/legis/LI/consCheck.cfm?txtType=HTM&ttl=75&div=0&chpt=33&sctn=34&subsctn=0).

Comment: I would say: If there is a stop-sign, you are "turning", not "merging" - the latter would require two parallel lanes become one (as others already stated). Hence I'd use my right turn signal.

Comment: @Gerhard: that connector road is for staying on Panther Hollow Road; the nearest possible turn is a full third of a mile before that stop sign. There's a stop sign because PennDOT believes that the way to compensate for insufficient merging space is to add a stop sign and make the merge *completely* impossible, instead of merely *almost* impossible. If it were merely a PennDOT-style break-your-neck right turn lane (constructed at the precise angle where your mirrors are still useless but your neck doesn't turn that far), it would have a yield sign instead of a stop sign.

Comment: @200_success: Er... that says when turn signals need to be used, but not which one.

Comment: @Martha: And the less said about the merge from Carnegie onto 376-E, or Squirrel Hill onto 376-E or Swissvale onto 376-E or... huh. I guess we kind of have a consistent problem here.

Comment: I know. You only need to have an "appropriate" signal. I personally interpret that to mean the signal that is consistent with the way you intend to turn the steering wheel.

Comment: @SeanDuggan: I was born and raised in California. The so-called merges in Pennsylvania make me want to cry. The only thing worse is when there's an actual acceleration lane, and *people don't know how to use it*. I suppose it's not their fault, but still, the zipper method is not rocket surgery. (I'm actually at the opposite end of the state, but same problems here. And insane merges aside, my favorite memory of Pittsburgh remains the sign saying "State Maintained Road" next to the worst stretch of so-called paved road this side of a war zone.)

Comment: The real correct answer is: "Using a turn signal is giving information to the enemy and should never be done."  - Source I grew up in The 'Burgh.

Comment: I accept that it *is* a requirement, but do not understand *why*  "signaling your intent" is required when there is no possible alternative.  Especially in this case where there is no acceleration lane and the access road is nearly parallel.to the road one is "merging" onto.

Comment: @MichaelJ. It's to alert whoever is to the right of a right-turning vehicle that "*hey, this vehicle is moving toward you!*" Perhaps there is cross traffic just after the turn, or a sidewalk crossing on the right side of the road. Cross traffic will look straight for approaching traffic and may not see you sitting there in the shade. A flashing indicator will alert them that you will soon become approaching traffic.

Comment: Even where there is a "zipper" or merge lane, using your left-turn blinker is a courtesy to alert drivers that you're pulling into the right-most travel lane.  You can be nice even when not required to by law :-)

Comment: @MichaelJ. "there is no possible alternative" ... check your sources on that one, in certain locations people WILL make an alternative... I've seen people make a U-turn over a curbed median, or just turn the wrong way and end up going the wrong way on the road. Using your signals correctly helps reassure other people that you know what you're doing and aren't going to do something else unexpected.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a stop sign at this intersection.
[image]

Your right hand signal would be appropriate while stopped at the sign, to signal your intent to cars behind you.  As soon as you've decided to proceed, you should switch to left signal to indicate your intention to oncoming traffic in the lane you're merging to.

Comment: Mind you, the question headline says "when merging in to a lane".  At the crossing shown, you're *not* merging in to a lane. It's simply a right-hand-turn at a stop sign.  So, yes, when "merging in to a lane" you signal left (or whichever way you are merging).  The situation shown is not "merging in to a lane".

Comment: Question -- what's the point of a right-turn signal here? What else could be your intent than turning right?

Comment: @Mehrdad: The way I usually look at it is that your signal may be of use to others. There may be pedestrians on the grassy areas next to the road who might not know that you can't turn left so they would be signaling to them as well. In this situation it is probably not really needed but in many situations it may be less obvious that there is only one option. And a rule of always indicate is better than a more subjective rule of "indicate unless its obvious".

Comment: @Chris: ah okay, gotcha. Sorry to go o a tangent, but another question: legally speaking, how do we figure out which ones are legally required?

Comment: Since there is apparently no choice at that intersection (there appears to be a barrier restricting a left turn), it seems that no turn signal is needed (except due to probable legal requirement). You're simply traveling in the required direction. There should be no confusion possible for those behind you nor on the main road. To me, a turn signal implies that something unexpected will be done, something different from traveling as required by the lane.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Not sure about legally required (certainly not in the US). I am not sure that failure to indicate is illegal in the UK. I suspect that if you were going to be prosecuted for that it would be under "dangerous driving" and would probably need to be in conjunction with something else (ie failing to indicate and thus causing an accident or near accident). I am not a lawyer though and my previous comment is just from experience of being a driver and also a pedestrian wondering what cars are actually doing.

Comment: Absolutely wrong. There's no "right turn" here.  Either don't signal, or hit the left blinker just as tho' it were an on-ramp sans Stop sign.

Comment: @Mehrdad you put the signal on for the direction you are going.  In this case it is without question a right hand turn, you turn on your right hand signal.  If you are moving in a forward motion and would like to merge to the left lane turn on your left hand signal.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Passing drivers and pedestrians with insufficient situational awareness (it happens, believe it or not) might have no idea you can't turn left there, and be left making poor or impulsive decisions as a result of their uncertainty. It's always advisable to use a signal when there is potential upside and no downside. Is there a reason you think using a signal here would be *detrimental*?

Answer (score 32):

Based on [Florida Drivers License Handbook](http://www.flhsmv.gov/handbooks/englishdriverhandbook.pdf)

> Signal your intent to merge onto the expressway

[image]

In this case, you'd switch between signals when merging -

[image]

So right signal when exiting until the stop sign, then left signal while merging.

Pennsylvania DOT [agrees](https://www.dot.state.pa.us/Public/DVSPubsForms/BDL/BDL%20Manuals/Manuals/PA%20Drivers%20Manual%20By%20Chapter/English/PUB%2095.pdf), but without pictures -

[image]

Comment: This is the right answer. People driving onto the highway need to be aware that you're merging. Flashing one's right turn signal might be technically correct, but the people driving on the road won't see it.

Comment: I agree. Using your left turn signal is the clearest indicator to the people you're merging into that you're coming. By the time you get to the gore point, you're already facing the direction of traffic and the action you're performing is a merge into the lane to your left, not a turn to your right.

Comment: Is this a highway on ramp, though? It looks too perpendicular for me to be comfortable merging there. I would likely stop and look left, since there isn't an acceleration lane.

Comment: @AdamStarrh looks like there is an acceleration lane (the dark pavement ending at the third tree shadow), but I'm blind.

Comment: @Raystafarian Hah. That looked more like a shoulder to me, but now that I've lived in Pennsylvania for a few years, I agree that it definitely could count as an onramp.

Comment: Sorry. I should have been clearer. Panther Hollow Rd. is not a highway. It's a road through a park in-town.

Comment: "Do NOT enter here!" - then it should be a solid line. Plenty of places like that in real life where it is a solid line, but the diagram should show a solid line - a dashed line means you can freely change lanes.

Comment: Yes, at first use right signal to inform drivers behind you you are turning right and finaly switch to left signal to inform drivers on Panther Hollow Rd. that you are about to merge into their line. I would do it regardless it is highway or minor road. Only suicidal maniac will try to actually turn left here.

Comment: Regarding the handbook figure; don't forget about the "rule" *Line ain't a wall; man ain't a tree* - If you cannot merge before the acceleration lane ends do **not** stop but drive along and merge as soon as possible. If you are in acceleration lane you can also "overtake" a vehicle (usually truck) going on the highway. (I live in central Europe)

Comment: nah, there's no "acceleration lane" here.  it's nothing more than a stop sign where you're stopped and turning right on to a road.

Comment: This isn't an acceleration lane, nor is this a highway, so the quoted passages are not relevant to the situation at hand.

Comment: Just to add context, while Panther Hollow Rd isn’t itself a highway, Pittsburgh has plenty of highway on-ramps configured exactly the same way as this example, including the stop sign.  Eg [Squirrel Hill entrance to 376 Eastbound](https://goo.gl/maps/4aEKk4Nz8uT2).

Comment: This answer may be technically correct but **nobody** signals right as described in this situation.  At most, people signal left to indicate their desire to merge.  And yes, it is a quirk of Pittsburgh that there are stop signs at the end of some onramps.

Comment: This is wrong again - you've misinterpreted the documentation.  Yes, you signal left when merging. No, you do NOT signal right unless you plan to pull onto the shoulder.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft you signal right because you took a ramp from another road, exiting to the right. Geez people, I don't know the specific area and I read the dark pavement as an acceleration lane; I don't need to be told that I'm incorrect more than once.

Answer (score 13):

This is the oakland zoo, just go. He was fishing for a DUI nothing more. You would use your right turn signal at the stop sign. Even though it's your only option. If there were an actual merge lane you would use your left signal to indicate a right lane to left lane merge, but there isn't. I was born and raised here in the Steelcity and work in Oakland.

Comment: right, it couldn't be simpler.  stop sign - turning right.

Comment: Heh... the FL diagram says "don't enter here" in the top half, yet the broken while line implies you can do otherwise.

Comment: ^_^ It's not the Oakland Zoo, but rather Schenley Park, but it is nice to get input from a native.

Answer (score 12):

In this particular case you should be using the **RIGHT TURN Signal**

You use the left turn signal only in the case where you merge or change from an acceleration lane such as the situation here:
[image]

In your particular case you where actually making a shallow right turn.

There are no actual rules printed as far as I can remember but you can check the driver's manual from various states it may be there.

Comment: This is really closer to a merge without the benefit of a merging lane than a right turn. Nobody behind you will have any illusion about where you are going (you can't go straight or turn left), and nobody already on Panther Hollow Rd will see your right turn signal anyway.

Comment: Hence my puzzlement about the Police involvement.  Though I can guess that he thought  the drive wanted to turn into against the traffic.

Comment: @Karlson the probable cause excuse seems most likely to me.

Comment: @chepner: the only-in-PA twist is that you're actually *already on Panther Hollow Rd* - all those gymnastics are so you can *stay* on Panther Hollow going east, instead of Boulevard of the Allies going west. (And if you want to continue going south-ish, you have to find the minuscule gap in the concrete barrier so you can merge right onto Overlook Dr. In fact, if the car in front of me at the stop sign were signaling right, I'd assume they had wanted to get on Overlook, missed the gap, and were now thoroughly confuzzled.)

Comment: just TBC Karlson's excellent large diagram shows what is ***NOT*** the case in this question.

Comment: @chepner "Right turn only" doesn't mean merge... I mean, it could be just a one way street, and no one thinks that's a merge.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple you use your turn signals to indicate to other drivers what your intentions are. You were correct to indicate left as your vehicle must turn slightly/merge to enter the main road from the access road on the right hand side of road.

As a fellow Pittsburgher driving the very same roads I use my left signal at this entrance onto the Boulevard.

Comment: As someone who is in Pittsburgh frequently but thinks that no one there can drive correctly, your answer confirms my belief.

Comment: "The answer is simple" which is why there are multiple conflicting answers!  In this case, it's not completely clear how to signal one's intentions; hence the question.

Comment: As someone who has driven in Boston for 30 yrs, I can confirm that this is the legally and socially correct answer, even if rarely done.  Signalling a right turn will only serve to confuse all other drivers.